# Create a Struct In Java Like C++

Tags: java, struct

i want to create an struct in java , like c++ :

```
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
};
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    MyStruct Struct;
    Struct.x = 0;
    std::cout << Struct.x;
    return 0;
}
```

can anyone help me ?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Java and classes.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @ArshiaAghaei When I first learn Java, I was disappointed when I realised there isn't struct in Java. But later I realised my disappointment was redundant as class can perform  the same task a struct needs to. Java classes are extremely easy to work with unlike C++ where you need to declare friends..etc. So feel free to use class instead of struct in Java.

Comment: Just like a struct in C++ is actually a class, a class in Java can be a struct. You lose nothing.

Comment: If you want to create a struct for parsing native memory have a look at https://github.com/marc-christian-schulze/structs4java

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class, which functions similarly to a `struct` in C++.

For example, a C++ `point` struct may look like

```
typedef struct __point {
   int x, y;
} point;
```

A Java `point` class has the form

```
final class Point { 
    private final double x;    // x-coordinate
    private final double y;    // y-coordinate

    // point initialized from parameters
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // accessor methods
    public double x() { return x; }
    public double y() { return y; }

    // return a string representation of this point
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    } 

}
```

We may then call the following:

```
Point q = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
System.out.println("q  = " + q);
System.out.println("x = " + q.x());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ircodes {
    public ircodes(String msg_id, String node_id, String frequency, String data) {
        this.hdr = new msg_hdr(4 + data.length(), Integer.parseInt(msg_id), Integer.parseInt(node_id));
        this.frequency = Integer.parseInt(frequency);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public class msg_hdr {
        int msg_len;
        int msg_id;
        int node_id;

        public msg_hdr(int msg_len, int msg_id, int node_id) {
            this.msg_len = 12 + msg_len;
            this.msg_id = msg_id;
            this.node_id = node_id;
        }
    }
    msg_hdr hdr;
    int frequency;
    String data;

    public ByteBuffer serialize() {
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(hdr.msg_len);
        buf.putInt(hdr.msg_len);
        buf.putInt(hdr.msg_id);
        buf.putInt(hdr.node_id);
        buf.putInt(frequency);
        buf.put(data.getBytes());
        return buf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have `struct`s like C or C++, but you can use Java classes and treat them like a `struct`. On top of that, you can of course declare all its members as public. (to work exactly like a `struct`)

```
class MyClass
{
    public int num;
}

MyClass m = new MyClass();
m.num = 5;
System.out.println(n.num);
```

One of the differences between a `struct` and a `class` is that a struct do not have methods. If you create a class without methods, it will work like a `struct`.

However, you can always put in methods (getters and setters) and set the variables as private like this (it doesn't hurt).

```
class MyClass
{
    private int num;
    public void setNum(int num){
        this.num = num
    }
    public int getNum(){
        return num
    }
}

MyClass m = new MyClass();
m.setNum(5);
System.out.println(n.getNum());
```

Java doesn't have `struct`s, but a Class can do exactly the same things a `struct` does.