# Convert structs in C++ to class in Java

Tags: java, c++, class, struct, structure

I have a code written in C++ which use struct and i want that code to be converted in java.

```
void main(){
  struct phone{
    char name[100];
    char num[10];
  };
  phone book[100];
  for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
    cin>>book[i].name;
    cin>>book[i].num;
  }
}
```

Please help me to convert this code to java

Comment: You could probably just take that code structure and use Java syntax...

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Totally depends if you need to do that at a marshalling level (to interface from java to c++), or if you just want to port that code at a semantical level. Note that something like `char name[100];` would be rarely used with professional standard c++ compliant code. The general preference to represent such would be `std::string name];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Struct In Java Like C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798152/create-a-struct-in-java-like-c)

Answer (score 3):

Java does not do structs. Instead you would create a class. You also need to start using String instead of char[], Java is strongly object oriented and is not very pretty when you try to use procedural style code in it. You also lose a lot of functionality trying to do it that way.

```
public class Phone {
    private String name;
    private String num;

    public Phone() { }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getNum() { return num; }

    public void setNum(String num) { this.num = num; }
}

public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phone[] book = new Phone[100];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            book[i] = new Phone();
            book[i].setName(scanner.next());
            book[i].setNum(scanner.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cin is for input i think, so you would prolly need to add a scanner and read the input

Comment: ah your right, I was thinking cout. man has it been awhile since c++ for me, going to edit it so it compiles for System.in